# classification in nltk is taking a lot of time

Tags: python, classification, nltk

I am training the nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier using questions from a large data set of around 35,000 questions. For classification the questions should be in a hashable format so I first tokenize all words and then create a list of tupples where the first element is the question( in dictionary format) and the second is the label. This works fine when i am using a small dataset but when i am using my complete dataset this program just runs for days..
As I think, the problem is that for a large dataset with 35,000 questions, it takes way too long in the process of creating the dictionaries. I don't know how I can do it in reasonable time.

Here is what I'm doing.

1. Tokenizing the words from all the questions.

`allw = set(word.lower() for passage in sub for word in word_tokenize(passage[0]))`

2. Creating a data structure for classifier to work on.

`t = [({word: (word in word_tokenize(x[0])) for word in allw}, x[1]) for x in sub]`

3. Training the classifier.

The above 3 steps are repeated 9 times with different set of Labels for each time i.e. we are doing all this for 35000 questions 9 times.

Comment: What does it mean to say the "question is in dictionary format?"

Comment: something like this    [({'this': True, 'love': True, 'deal': False, 'tired': False, 'feel': False, 'is': False, 'am': False, 'an': False, 'sandwich': True, 'ca': False, 'best': False, '!': False, 'what': False, '.': True}, 'pos'), . . .]

Comment: You should add more detail about exactly what you are doing - code would help. I don't think creating 35000 dictionaries would take days. It should be very fast - but I don't know how you are processing your text to create the dictionaries, where I assume the bottleneck will be. Of course, this is all hand-waving and you should profile your code to get a concrete idea of where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Also, your `tuple` is not hashable. For a tuple to be hashable, all of it's elements must be hashable, and dictionaries are *not* hashable. So a tuple containing a dictionary is not hashable.

Comment: Also, please add additional details as an edit to the **question**, not as a comment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hey,thanks for your time .I have included the code in the question.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful. Also, you need to create the 35k dictionary only once, I assume. After it's created, just serialize it, save it to disk, and subsequently - use the dictionary from disk (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).